# what's the difference between those two ways to initialize fields in Java?

Tags: java, variable-assignment

1. Assign value to field at the same time with field declaration
2. Assign value to field in the constructor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ***What's the difference between those two ways to initialize fields in Java?***

Not much! The main difference is that if you assign it at the point of declaration, it will apply to *all* constructors. That is, there's no way you can forget to add the initialization to any future constructors.

Have a look at the official [Initializing Fields](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) trail.

May be worth noting that if you initialize the fields at the declaration, it happens *before* the constructor starts executing.

As a rule of thumb, I usually initialize the "dead simple" fields at the declaration (when there is no doubt what the initial value should be). This "cleans up" For instance

```
class SomeClass {

    List<Integer> currentNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int counter = 0;

    // ...
}
```

while as if there is the slightest chance that I may want different behaviors in different constructors, I leave it to the constructor.

Comment: Another difference might be the order in which the fields are initialized.

Comment: Note that it happens before the real body of the constructor starts executing, but *after* any call to `super(...)`.

Comment: The first one is for creating default factory object and the second is for specialized factory object.

Answer (score 4):

In both cases, the value will only be assigned *after* the superclass constructor has executed.

For the first option, you have to be able to determine the value without reference to any constructor parameters.

For the second option, you'll need to assign the value in *every* constructor overload.

Basically I tend to favour the second option when the value depends on constructor parameters (usually that's all I would want it to depend on) and the first option when the value will be the same for *any* newly initialized instance. I *tend* not to mix and match for a single field, using an initializer with the declaration and *also* assigning it in some constructor overloads, but even that can be useful occasionally. (Imagine a collection which has a size of 0 for most constructors, but has one constructor which takes an initial set of values.)

While you *can* refer to other instance members in variable declarations, I prefer not to - calling instance methods when your object is only partially initialized is brittle, and referring to other variables relies on the variable ordering, which feels ugly to me.

Comment: Your second statement is wrong. I can do `int i = 1; int j = i;`.

Comment: @aioobe: Ick. Thanks, will correct. (You can't in C#, which confused me.)

Answer (score 1):

(1) is a syntax sugar for (2) (with the exception of static fields)

Answer (score 0):

It does exactly the same, just at different times in the object instantiation life-cycle. Have a look [here](http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/2238491/The-Essence-of-OOP-using-Java-Static-Initializer-Blocks.htm) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case the field will be created when the class is initialised and assigned directly the value you hace declared for it, while in the second case the field will be created and assigned a default value (null if it's an object, 0 if it's an int, etc.) and then assigned the correct value when the constructor is executed. Of course practically there's usually not much difference for you since the result in both cases is the same: when you create an instance of this class after the constructor returns the field is initialised correctly. I guess the first approach would be more usefull if you have more than one constructors and a field which should have the same value regardless of which constructor has been called.